# Strange table alignment in page

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, alignment

Could anyone lend me a hand and some wisdom as why the `table:S1` and `table:S3` (***see picture below***) are not centered in the page like `table:S2`? I'm drawing a blank here. Here's

[image: The end result of the MWE]

Below is the the MWE I used to produce this document:

```
\documentclass{book}

% *****************************************************************************
%                                    Preamble
% *****************************************************************************

% Additional Packages
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % to deal with those pesky ASCII symbols!
\usepackage{siunitx} % use this package module for SI units
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}

% *****************************************************************************
% *****************************************************************************
%                                 End of Preamble
% *****************************************************************************
% *****************************************************************************
\begin{document} % Fun time!


% --> Custom commands <--

\newcommand{\tn}[1]{\textsuperscript{#1}}
\newcommand{\TN}[1]{\makebox[0pt][l]{\tn{#1}}}

% -- End of custom commands --

% ==> Case in point <==

\section{My first fully compiled MWE in TeX!}   


    \lipsum[1] % Generating dummy text!


    \begin{threeparttable}[!htbp]
        \caption{Experimentally determined spectroscopic parameters of the detected rotamer of PG}
        \label{table:S1} % should go after \caption
        \centering
        \sisetup{table-align-text-post=false}
        \begin{tabular}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} l S[table-format=4.1(2)] S[table-format=3.4(2)] S[table-format=3.4(2)] }
            \toprule
            & A \tnote{a} & B & C \\        
            \midrule
            \ce{^{13}C} (1)& 3075.3 (31)\tnote{b}& 733.2825 (30)& 697.0386 (27) \\ 
            \ce{^{13}C} (2)& 3086.3 (15) & 736.5933 (22)& 699.4114 (17) \\ 
            \ce{^{13}C} (4)& 3055.3 (22) & 736.9399 (26)& 698.2864 (24) \\ 
            \ce{^{13}C} (5)& 3064.7 (23) & 731.8158 (29)& 693.8030 (27) \\ 
            \ce{^{13}C} (6)& 3085.0 (27) & 728.5381 (35)& 692.0961 (30) \\ 
            \ce{^{13}C} (7)& 3052.6 (32) & 732.9437 (36)& 694.8316 (36) \\ 
            \ce{^{13}C} (8)& 3056.3 (35) & 737.5525 (40)& 699.6777 (51) \\ 
            \ce{^{15}N}    & 3042.1 (12) & 733.0221 (15)& 697.1036 (21) \\ 
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
        \begin{tablenotes}[flushleft]\footnotesize
            \item[a] $A$, $B$, and $C$ are the rotational constants (in \si{MHz});
            $\chi_{aa}$, $\chi_{bb}$, and $\chi_{cc}$ are elements of the $^{14}$N nuclear quadrupole coupling tensor (in \si{MHz}).
            \item[b] Standard errors indicated in parentheses in units of the last digit.
        \end{tablenotes}
    \end{threeparttable} 

\begin{table}[!htbp]
    \centering
    \caption{Observed frequencies and residuals (in \si{MHz}) for the observed transitions of \ce{^{13}C} (\ce{C_{10}}) isotopic species of phenylglycinol.}
    \label{table:S2}
    \sisetup{table-align-text-post=false}
    \begin{tabular}{@{\hspace{\tabcolsep}\extracolsep{\fill}} cccccc S[table-format=5.4] S[table-format=1.4] }
        \toprule
{J\textasciiacute}         &
{K\textasciiacute$_{-1}$}  &
{K\textasciiacute$_{+1}$}  &
{J\textacutedbl}           &
{K\textacutedbl$_{-1}$}    &
{K\textacutedbl$_{+1} $}   &
{$ \nu_{obs} $}            &
{$ \nu_{obs} - \nu_{cal} $} \\  
        \midrule
        5   & 1 & 5 & 4 & 1 & 4 &  7084.9419    &  0.0170 \\
        5   & 0 & 5 & 4 & 0 & 4 &  7173.7289    &  0.0526 \\
        5   & 2 & 4 & 4 & 2 & 3 &  7182.1213    &  0.0253 \\
        5   & 1 & 4 & 4 & 1 & 3 &  7277.2026    & -0.0193 \\
        6   & 0 & 6 & 5 & 0 & 5 &  8603.3344    &  0.0928 \\
        6   & 2 & 5 & 5 & 2 & 4 &  8617.6872    &  0.0424 \\
        6   & 1 & 5 & 5 & 1 & 4 &  8731.3175    &  0.0139 \\
        7   & 0 & 7 & 6 & 0 & 6 & 10030.0312    & -0.0240 \\
        7   & 2 & 6 & 6 & 2 & 5 & 10052.6810    & -0.0383 \\
        7   & 1 & 6 & 6 & 1 & 5 & 10184.6218    &  0.0138 \\
        8   & 0 & 7 & 7 & 0 & 7 & 11453.7239    & -0.0258 \\
        8   & 2 & 7 & 7 & 2 & 6 & 11487.1502    & -0.0909 \\        
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}     

\begin{table}[!htbp]
    \centering
    \caption{Experimentally determined spectroscopic parameters of the detected rotamer of PG}
    \label{table:S3} % should go after \caption
    \sisetup{table-align-text-post=false}
    \begin{tabular}{@{\hspace{\tabcolsep}\extracolsep{\fill}} c S[table-format=4.1(2)] S[table-format=3.4(2)] S[table-format=3.4(2)] }
        \toprule
        & A \tn{a} & B & C \\       
        \midrule
        \ce{^{13}C} (1)& 3075.3 (31)\tn{b}& 733.2825 (30)& 697.0386 (27) \\ 
        \ce{^{13}C} (2)& 3086.3 (15) & 736.5933 (22)& 699.4114 (17) \\ 
        \ce{^{13}C} (4)& 3055.3 (22) & 736.9399 (26)& 698.2864 (24) \\ 
        \ce{^{13}C} (5)& 3064.7 (23) & 731.8158 (29)& 693.8030 (27) \\ 
        \ce{^{13}C} (6)& 3085.0 (27) & 728.5381 (35)& 692.0961 (30) \\ 
        \ce{^{13}C} (7)& 3052.6 (32) & 732.9437 (36)& 694.8316 (36) \\ 
        \ce{^{13}C} (8)& 3056.3 (35) & 737.5525 (40)& 699.6777 (51) \\ 
        \ce{^{15}N}    & 3042.1 (12) & 733.0221 (15)& 697.1036 (21) \\ 
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \raggedright\footnotesize
    \begin{enumerate}[label=\tn{\alph*},leftmargin=*]
        \item $A$, $B$, and $C$ are the rotational constants (in \si{MHz});
        $\chi_{aa}$, $\chi_{bb}$, and $\chi_{cc}$ are elements of the $^{14}$N nuclear quadrupole coupling tensor (in \si{MHz}).
        \item Standard errors indicated in parentheses in units of the last digit.
    \end{enumerate}
\end{table} 

\end{document}
```

Much obliged!

***UPDATE*** - There is a moral to take from this question, after all! Proper LaTeX code formatting is needed too! Apparently, a blank line can make much difference! This is my naïve conclusion, so far.

> I, myself, have had many failures and I've learned that if you are not failing a lot, you are probably not being as creative as you could be -you aren't stretching your imagination.
>   *- J. Backus*

Comment: yoor code can not be compiled. what is `\textasciiacute` etc?

Comment: @Zarko, it makes use of `\fontenc` to place symbols. I'll amend my MWE.

Comment: @Strelok - I suspect that rather than writing `J\textasciiacute`, `J\textacutedbl`, etc., you should be writing (in math mode) `J'`, `J''`, etc. At least, that's what I did in the middle table of my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- The first table isn't centered (horizontally) because you didn't embed the `threeparttable` environment inside a `table` environment. Then, move the `\centering` instruction *outside* the `threeparttable` environment.
- To understand why the third table isn't centered, it's necessary to understand how `\centering` and `\raggedright` (and `\raggedleft`, for that matter) work. Essentially, they get to do their work *at the end of a paragraph*. In your code, there's no empty line, and no other type of paragraph break, between `\end{tabular}` and `\raggedright`. You can (should be able to?) guess that `\raggedright`, not `\centering`, is what's in force at the end of the (logical) paragraph.

Here are all three tables on one page, all three centered horizontally.

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[margin=1in,letterpaper]{geometry}
\usepackage{array} % for \newcolumntype macro
\newcolumntype{C}{>{$}c<{$}}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\usepackage[skip=0.333\baselineskip]{caption}

\begin{document} 

\newcommand{\tn}[1]{\textsuperscript{#1}}
\newcommand{\TN}[1]{\makebox[0pt][l]{\tn{#1}}}

\begin{table}[h!]
\centering % Now placed *before* \begin{threeparttable}

\begin{threeparttable}[!htbp]

\caption{Experimentally determined spectroscopic parameters of the detected rotamer of PG}
\label{table:S1}

\sisetup{table-align-text-post=false}
\begin{tabular}{@{} l S[table-format=4.1(2)] 
                      S[table-format=3.4(2)] 
                      S[table-format=3.4(2)] @{}}
\toprule
     & {$A$\,\tnote{a}} & {$B$} & {$C$} \\        
\midrule
     \ce{^{13}C} (1)& 3075.3 (31)\tnote{b}& 733.2825 (30)& 697.0386 (27) \\ 
     \ce{^{13}C} (2)& 3086.3 (15) & 736.5933 (22)& 699.4114 (17) \\ 
     \ce{^{13}C} (4)& 3055.3 (22) & 736.9399 (26)& 698.2864 (24) \\ 
     \ce{^{13}C} (5)& 3064.7 (23) & 731.8158 (29)& 693.8030 (27) \\ 
     \ce{^{13}C} (6)& 3085.0 (27) & 728.5381 (35)& 692.0961 (30) \\ 
     \ce{^{13}C} (7)& 3052.6 (32) & 732.9437 (36)& 694.8316 (36) \\ 
     \ce{^{13}C} (8)& 3056.3 (35) & 737.5525 (40)& 699.6777 (51) \\ 
     \ce{^{15}N}    & 3042.1 (12) & 733.0221 (15)& 697.1036 (21) \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\begin{tablenotes}[flushleft]
\footnotesize
\item[a] $A$, $B$, and $C$ are the rotational constants (in \si{\mega\hertz}).
$\chi_{aa}$, $\chi_{bb}$, and $\chi_{cc}$ are elements of the $^{14}$N nuclear 
quadrupole coupling tensor (in \si{\mega\hertz}).
\item[b] Standard errors indicated in parentheses in units of the last digit.
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable} 
\end{table}

\begin{table}[!h]
\centering
\caption{Observed frequencies and residuals (in \si{MHz}) for the observed transitions of \ce{^{13}C} (\ce{C_{10}}) isotopic species of phenylglycinol.}
\label{table:S2}
\sisetup{table-align-text-post=false}
\begin{tabular}{@{} CCCCCC S[table-format= 5.4] 
                           S[table-format=-1.4] @{}}
\toprule
J' & K'_{-1} & K'_{+1} & J'' & K''_{-1} & K''_{+1} 
& {$\nu_{\mathrm{obs}}$} 
& {$\nu_{\mathrm{obs}} - \nu_{\mathrm{cal}}$} \\  
\midrule
  5   & 1 & 5 & 4 & 1 & 4 &  7084.9419    &  0.0170 \\
  5   & 0 & 5 & 4 & 0 & 4 &  7173.7289    &  0.0526 \\
  5   & 2 & 4 & 4 & 2 & 3 &  7182.1213    &  0.0253 \\
  5   & 1 & 4 & 4 & 1 & 3 &  7277.2026    & -0.0193 \\
  6   & 0 & 6 & 5 & 0 & 5 &  8603.3344    &  0.0928 \\
  6   & 2 & 5 & 5 & 2 & 4 &  8617.6872    &  0.0424 \\
  6   & 1 & 5 & 5 & 1 & 4 &  8731.3175    &  0.0139 \\
  7   & 0 & 7 & 6 & 0 & 6 & 10030.0312    & -0.0240 \\
  7   & 2 & 6 & 6 & 2 & 5 & 10052.6810    & -0.0383 \\
  7   & 1 & 6 & 6 & 1 & 5 & 10184.6218    &  0.0138 \\
  8   & 0 & 7 & 7 & 0 & 7 & 11453.7239    & -0.0258 \\
  8   & 2 & 7 & 7 & 2 & 6 & 11487.1502    & -0.0909 \\        
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}     

\begin{table}[!htbp]
\centering
\caption{Experimentally determined spectroscopic parameters of the detected rotamer of PG}
\label{table:S3}

\sisetup{table-align-text-post=false}
\begin{tabular}{@{} l S[table-format=4.1(2)] 
                      S[table-format=3.4(2)] 
                      S[table-format=3.4(2)] @{}}
\toprule
  & {$A$\,\tn{a}} & {$B$} & {$C$} \\       
\midrule
  \ce{^{13}C} (1)& 3075.3 (31)\tn{b}& 733.2825 (30)& 697.0386 (27) \\ 
  \ce{^{13}C} (2)& 3086.3 (15) & 736.5933 (22)& 699.4114 (17) \\ 
  \ce{^{13}C} (4)& 3055.3 (22) & 736.9399 (26)& 698.2864 (24) \\ 
  \ce{^{13}C} (5)& 3064.7 (23) & 731.8158 (29)& 693.8030 (27) \\ 
  \ce{^{13}C} (6)& 3085.0 (27) & 728.5381 (35)& 692.0961 (30) \\ 
  \ce{^{13}C} (7)& 3052.6 (32) & 732.9437 (36)& 694.8316 (36) \\ 
  \ce{^{13}C} (8)& 3056.3 (35) & 737.5525 (40)& 699.6777 (51) \\ 
  \ce{^{15}N}    & 3042.1 (12) & 733.0221 (15)& 697.1036 (21) \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\raggedright % leave the preceding line blank!
\footnotesize
\begin{enumerate}[label=\tn{\alph*},leftmargin=*]
\item $A$, $B$, and $C$ are the rotational constants (in \si{MHz}). 
$\chi_{aa}$, $\chi_{bb}$, and $\chi_{cc}$ are elements of the $^{14}$N nuclear 
quadrupole coupling tensor (in \si{\mega\hertz}).
\item Standard errors indicated in parentheses in units of the last digit.
\end{enumerate}
\end{table} 

\end{document}
```

Comment: I've thought that LaTeX was 'insensitive' to blank lines - a bit like FORTRAN is insensitive to spaces.

So, the word of advice is - keep you code neat and tidy, and don't have things on top of each other.

Comment: @Strelok - The view that "LaTeX was 'insensitive' to blank lines" is definitely wrong when it comes to display-math mode. In TeX and LaTeX, blank lines serve to generate paragraph breaks. Blank lines in displayed math environments cannot be allowed, as otherwise there would be tremendous (and likely irreconcilable) ambiguity as to what the implied paragraph breaks are supposed to mean.